# How to log in to MACM API

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud

When trying to use the IBM Bluemix MACM BasicAuth login per REST as in here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYK7J_8.5.0/macm/macm_bas_auth_login_api.html

you may get the following error code:

```
Error 404: EJCBD0006E: The resolution of a URI failed. Refer to the SystemOut.log for more detailed information.
```

What is the cause?

Comment: Got it: You need to send a POST request.

Comment: Sven, you might add this as an answer and accept it by yourself in order to show the status of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *"Error 404: EJCBD0006E: The resolution of a URI failed."*  you can check if the userid has at least USER role on this page:

Administration > Manage Pages > search on unique name contains "hidden" > click Key icon next to Web Content Management page > click on USER role > add user or user's group if not currently assigned.